# Incorrectly positioned checkbox with Razor layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm busy with a Core 2 MVC application, and where `IsAdmin` is a `bool`, the following Razor markup:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="IsAdmin" style="display: inline-block;"></label>
    <input asp-for="IsAdmin" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="IsAdmin" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

it renders as in the below image, regardless of screen, and `form-group`, width:

[image]

My only custom CSS is all for elements selected by `id`, and has nothing to do with forms layout. I've even tried making the label `display: inline-block` to no avail. What is wrong here?

How do I achieve the checkbox inline with the label?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a result of not actually adding the HTML, CSS classes, etc. that Bootstrap requires for checkboxes. You haven't specified which version of Bootstrap you're using (or even that you *are* using Bootstrap, before I retagged your question), so here's the two different options:

**[Bootstrap 4](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios)**

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="IsAdmin" />
    <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="IsAdmin"></label>
</div>
```

**[Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#checkboxes-and-radios)**

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="IsAdmin" />
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.IsAdmin)
    </label>
</div>
```